# Javascript in browser IS able to use sockets/get info from web by itself?

Tags: javascript, ajax, sockets, browser, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to open sockets and get data from web in JavaScript.

My aim is: to work with web data using JS.
I have looked for XmlHttp/AJAX solution, but I have found one note, that AJAX can be used only for calling localhost programs, which will be used as proxy and then only returns data from web.

It's because of sandbox model in browsers, which don't allow to work with sockets/other sites from JavaScript, and it works only in localhost.

Are there any solutions with JS to work with other world?

Comment: Ajax is not limited to 'localhost'

Comment: open method can only call other program from localhost, which get info from tcp/ip and returns data in js, because of browser-security, no?

Comment: It's not limited to localhost.  It's limited to the same-origin.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is due to cross domain request security, where you can't asynchronously get data from a domain which doesn't match the current host (this includes subdomains). You can however use jsonp, but this relies on the service that you're quering to supply the data in a jsonp format (a function call with the json data as a response).

If you have no control over the services you're requesting (which i assume you don't), you can use a javascript library, such as YUI or jQuery to perform the cross domain request for you (which typically uses Flash as the data proxy). However this will only work if you the site in question allows cross domain requests from your domain (defined in crossdomain.xml).

Comment: jQuery and YUI do not do cross-domain requests, and Flash cannot either (unless there is document on the cross-domain server allowing it to do so).  The JSONP statement is true, however.